# How can I show random sprites for an animation on a fruit machine wheel? - Android

Tags: java, android, android-image

I'm creating a fruit machine in Android.
The wheels on the fruit machine need to spin, using sprites at random.
There will be three wheels, each with three icons. I need to be able to make these icons random, and have them appear to be moving downwards. I have thought of a way to do it but don't think it's efficient, there must be a better way?

My idea is to have an array of 4 icons for each reel. hidden, top, middle and bottom.
I would use a transition to move the bottom one off and destroy, move the middle to the bottom, the top to the middle and the top hidden to the top. After the transition, I would then change the array to show the change, and introduce a new random sprite at the top.

Does this sound like the best way... or is there another?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the sprites in an array, then choose an item at random by

```
Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
int index = random.nextInt(4);
```

for an array of size 4.